# Rails/Ruby dry-monads error on simple API call

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, monads

I am testing out Shftcos API boilerplate, which has a ton of additions including the dry-monads gem which I've not encountered before.

On a service call to fetch FakeStoreApi products I am getting error thrown  by this which looks like traverse:

> Cannot traverse an untyped list (StandardError) with the code as below in the service call.

```
require 'faraday'
require 'json'

class FetchProductsService < ApplicationService
  def call
    result = yield fetch_products

    Success(result)
  end

  private

  def fetch_products
    products = []
    response = Faraday.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/products') 
    if response.status == 200
      products = JSON.parse(response.body)
    end
    products
  end
end
```

Untyped list? Does anyone know why as this should return an array of the product data?
Have we got to use some list styles on this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue as you, the problem was because I did not return a Monad in my function,

You may want to add `Success` at the end of your function

```rb
  def fetch_products
    products = []
    response = Faraday.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/products') 
    if response.status == 200
      products = JSON.parse(response.body)
    end
    Success(products) # <-- Wrap it here!
  end
```